# Cannot delete files in Rubbish bin in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, trash

I have some folders and files that  do not get deleted in the trash folder.

I logged in as root using 
`sudo su` 
then 
`rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/files/*` 
but nothing happens.

Can anyone help with a step-by-step solution please?

Comment: You DO NOT want files in the trash to be deleted?  But the `rm` command you're trying to run is to delete the files.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I do want the files deleted.

Answer (score 1):

root's Trash directory?

I assume you want to empty your user's trash, not root's.  If you "sudo su" then "~" will (probably[0]) expand to "/root", which is unlikely to be what you meant.

Why are you using sudo to do this anyway?

If you need to be root (for some reason) to delete these files, try:

```
sudo rm /home/<username>/.local/share/Trash/files/*
```

or similar.

[0] whether it does or not depends on how much of the environment gets inherited when sudo is run, but I think by default it does

Comment: All I get is: rm: cannot remove ‘/home/<my username>/.local/share/Trash/files/pt7sNdLvbt’: Is a directory
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/<my username>/.local/share/Trash/files/XMKx-BRJn1’: Is a directory

Comment: `rm -rf /home/<username>/.local/share/Trash/files/*` .... I.e. the `rm -r` command is to be used for deleting folders.